# Creating a calendar event from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a script that will pull from my google sheet to create a google calendar event, but I keep receiving this error:

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createAllDayEvent. (line 21, file "sheets to calendar")

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
function sheets_to_calendar(){


    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxx@group.calendar.google.com");
    var Title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J1').getValue();
  
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getYear();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;  if(month.toString().length==1){var month = '0'+month;}
    var day = date.getDate(); if(day.toString().length==1){var day = '0'+day;}
    var hour = date.getHours(); if(hour.toString().length==1){var hour = '0'+hour;}
    var minu = date.getMinutes(); if(minu.toString().length==1){var minu = '0'+minu;}
    var seco = date.getSeconds(); if(seco.toString().length==1){var seco = '0'+seco;}
    var date = year+'·'+month+'·'+day+'·'+hour+'·'+minu+'·'+seco;
    Logger.log(date);

    var description = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F13').getValue();
  

    eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Title, date, {description: "test"});
  
}
```

Comment: date must be a date object, not a string. Simply remove all the useless date to string part

Comment: like @Sergeinsas is saying, in the error you see two times string, but the second parameter must be a date. See this doc: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEvent(String,Date,Object)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`createAllDayEvent(title, date, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-date,-options) documentation, the `date` used **must** be an object of type `Date`.

Taking this into account, you can do the following modification:

```
var date  = new Date(month + day + ',' + year);
```

Also, please bear in mind that since you are creating an *all day event*, only the date will be taken into account.

#### Reference

- [Calendar Class Apps Script createAllDayEvent(title, date, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-date,-options);
- [Working With Dates](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates).

Comment: I tried the modification! Now I receive this error:
Exception: The parameters (String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createAllDayEvent. (line 21, file "sheets to calendar")